# win32 plugin build error in flutter_openvpn with Flutter 2.0 / Dart 12

Tags: flutter, dart, winapi, dart-ffi

I get this error when I build the app for iOS: `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`.

**[Screenshot of the build error in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iESL.png)**

Comment: Hi Yacino, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to copy error message text instead of attaching screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by an old version of the `win32` package that uses Dart FFI in a way that was prohibited with the release of Dart 2.12.

To fix this, update the `win32` package. If the package is a transitive dependency, you can use [`dependency_overrides`](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67086172/13561336 thank you it's fixed

Comment: Which command fix this problem?

Comment: did not solve the problem in my case